# Bootstrap 3.0 : alignment of elements on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have two divs like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><img></div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12"><p></p></div>
</div>
```

On smaller screen less than 480px i want to show 



 before **img** , i tried to use floats but that didn't work .

Can you please guide how can i do it .

Comment: what exactly do you want? it's not clear... however, do you have a `container` or a `fluid-container` on top of the row div?

Comment: @dippas I don't think that's a right duplicate...

Comment: @OvidiuDolha that is not a duplicate , i want right div to come first in mobile view